# How to set a column to fit the longest text programmatically in Excel?

Tags: .net, excel

In Excel, you can double-click a column header (actually the line between 2 column headers) and the column to the left will expand in width to fit the length of the longest text. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I am using Excel 2010 with C# and .Net framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use:

```
    Rng.Columns.AutoFit()
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I just had to change it slightly to Rng.EntireColumn.AutoFit().